# Two 20 amps GFCI outlets used for kitchen back splash

Tags: kitchens

Is this properly connected or need to be changed?
Note: Bare ground wire connected to both A and B metal boxes and to green screws on outlets A and B

Wired used from main Panel to both A and B outlet is 12awg/3 with ground, Red, Black, white and bare ground.

From main panel to 1st Outlet A, cut the red wire in the box and connected the end side of the wire from main panel side to Brass screw on line side of outlet, the other end of the red wire capped and taped inside box, the remaining red wire between box A and box B is now (Dead wire.)
**White wire cut in box A and connected one end on the silver screw line side of outlet and the other end connected in the hole behind outlet on same line side, (Instead of Pig Tail wire) Is this good not to use pig tail** this wire section continues to outlet B and connected on silver screw on line side and now the Black wire connected on brass screw line side and the red end wire also capped and taped in Box B.
In Main Panel I used a Double 20A pole breaker.
On the outlets the LOAD side screws did not use them at all.
Thank you.

Comment: So if I got this right you won the lottery and cut off and capped a ungrounded conductor and have 2 GFCI's on the same breaker. Other than that is has been a long day. I see 2 GFCI' fed from the line side and nothing going to a load, wasted conductor & GFCI

Comment: This is a common multi-wire branch circuit (MWBC).  Completely routine and it sounds like he's done it right except for the pigtailing the neutral.

Comment: I rather be safe than taking chances for few pennies, especially when it comes to Kitchen, bathrooms or laundry, I thank you for the encouragement Mr. Beal.

Answer (score 1):

If your wiring looks like this.

[image]

Then it's basically right.  The only thing I'd change, is to use a pigtail for the neutral, instead of the backstab on the receptacle. In fact, this is required by code (300.13(B)).

Depending on the devices you're using, the backstab terminals may only be rated for use with 14 AWG wire.  In which case, the 12 AWG you're using is too big anyway.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 3 Wiring Methods
>
> #### Article 300 General Requirements for Wiring Methods and Materials
>
> **300.13 Mechanical and Electrical Continuity — Conductors.**
>
> **(B) Device Removal.** In multiwire branch circuits, the
> continuity of a grounded conductor shall not depend on
> device connections such as lampholders, receptacles, and
> so forth, where the removal of such devices would interrupt
> the continuity.

Comment: The neutral must be pigtailed - this is mandatory.  That is so if you remove outlet A for service, neutral will still be connected to outlet B.

Comment: Thanks @WolfHarper, I forgot that it was required. Edited.

Comment: Hi Wolf Harper, Your drawing is exactly how I did it, just to let you know, I just finish changing it to a pig Tail. I feel a lot better now than have something bothering me in my head.My concern was that if I plug in two high amperage units, such as coffee maker, oven toaster etc. one on each outlet, I could be having too much amps going through the outlet itself and cause melting or fire, and I never thought about if outlet A is disconnected I will not have power in outlet B. even though I have a double pole breaker in the main panel, but that is safer in my book. I thank you.